# Typewriter look from a text file

Tags: javascript, timeout

I'm a really new Javascript person who for the first time is trying to write (rather than copy) code for a page.  Simply put, I wish to read a text file then display the characters one at a time in a div already created.  The 'get' corks fine and the data variable receives the string, however, I get a 'Line 1' input past error from the browser when this executes.  Probably 10 things wrong with how I am going about it, but any direction welcome.

```
enter code here

<div id='textelement' style="width:400px; height:200px ;overflow:auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("Comments.txt", function (data) 
{
    var displaytxt = "";
    displaytxt = data;
    function nextchar () 
        {
        if (displaytxt.length > 0) 
            {
            $('#textelement').append(displaytxt.substr(0, 1));
            displaytxt = displaytxt.substr(1);
            setTimeout(nextchar, 70);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you did not escape your function properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("Comments.txt", function (data) 
{
    var displaytxt = "";
    displaytxt = data;
    function nextchar () 
        {
        if (displaytxt.length > 0) 
            {
            $('#textelement').append(displaytxt.substr(0, 1));
            displaytxt = displaytxt.substr(1);
            setTimeout(nextchar, 70);
            }
        }
 }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That clears the parsing error.  Any thoughts on why code still is not running?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this a while I found that:
1.  I never called my function 'nextchar' therefore it never ran.  Silly me.
2.  setTimeout needs a strange syntax using the function() {} in order to pass parameters.  Why is this?

The code below now works for me.

greg

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function nextchar(displaytxt) {
    if (displaytxt.length > 0) {
        $('#textelement').append(displaytxt.substring(0, 1));
        displaytxt = displaytxt.substr(1);
        setTimeout(function () { nextchar(displaytxt); }, 70);
    }
}
$.get("PatientComments.txt", function (data) {
    var displaytxt = "";
    displaytxt = data;
    alert(displaytxt);
    nextchar(displaytxt);
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error);
});
</script>
```